# set suggestions on androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app in which i used a `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` I have an arraylist which contains different values now i want to set the suggestions of `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` from that array list. I tried a lot but it didn't work well.
I also toast in `onQueryTextChange` to test either it is working or not but it is not working because when i change the text i didn't get the toasr

```
public static ArrayList<String> phoneNo=new ArrayList<>(); // This one contains names
public static ArrayList<String> cname=new ArrayList<>(); // This one contains phone numbers
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
        final String[] from = new String[] {"contacts"};
        final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(home_Activity,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                null,
                from,
                to,
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

}
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.sView);
     searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mAdapter);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);
                String txt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contacts"));
                searchView.setQuery(txt, true);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                // Your code here
                return true;
            }
        });



        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                populateAdapter(s);
                Toast.makeText(home_Activity, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });


}
```